What constraint can be added for an intuitive and useful warehouse floor?
For my problem there are 2076 boxes, 40 columns, with the first 13 columns having 60 rows (or 60 boxes) and then next 27 columns only have 48 rows. So if you draw the outline its a polygon with 6 sides and then with a grid inside. I want to assign a category to each box, ranging from categories 1 to 7. Define a variable $x_{ijk}$, $i$ taking values until 60 for the first 13 columns and 48 for the next 27, and k being one of the 7 categories. This variable is 1 if the box $(i,j)$ is assigned to category $k$. Each category has a theoretical optimal proportion of all the boxes (of the 2076) it takes, which I denote as $p_k$ (for $k \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$). Now I want to get as close as possible to those proportions, hence I formulated it as a minimization of the square difference.
To give more context each square represents a rack where a certain product can be placed in a warehouse, so it would make sense for the space assigned to categories to be one area rather than disjointed squares everywhere. Also if there were 2 categories, having one big square in the middle and the rest around engulfing it, again this wouldn't make much sense. How would I go about creating an intuitive constraint such that the areas assigned to categories are useful for a warehouse?
\begin{equation}
    min \sum_{k} ( \rho_{k} - \frac{\sum_i\sum_j x_{ijk}}{2076})^2
\end{equation}
Such that:
\begin{equation}
     \sum_i\sum_j x_{ijk} \leq 2076 \quad \forall k
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{k} x_{ijk} = 1 \quad \forall (i,j)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    x_{ijk} \in \{0,1\}
\end{equation}
EDIT: For clarity of the problem, below I have added the approximate ground plan of each "box":

Each box here should take values 1 to 7 depending on which box is assigned to which category.

Is this a hard constraint, or can you add a penalty term to the objective to discourage these holes but still allow them?

Welcome to OR.SE. I am unsure if I understand the problem properly, but some points could be considered. A) How the index $i$ can take the difference value from two sets simultaneously, (1-60, 1-48)? B) How is the $p_k$ estimated to be the optimal category type? C) What does actually $\text{Box}_{(i,j)}$ mean? D) Could you explain more about the problem, specifically, the first 3 lines?

@J.Dionisio It should be a hard constraint, it really wouldn't work for my warehouse for the categories to be dispersed (the workers wouldn't be able to memorize the plan easily enough)

@A.Omidi A) I suppose I'm unsure and this would be another point I would appreciate help with. B) $p_k$ being optimal is internal values that my company wants, so this isn't something variable. C) $\text{Box}_{(i,j)} is a literal box where products can be placed. D) To explain the problem I will try to edit the original problem and add a picture of the ground plan.

@sir.edward You want to have a connected graph for each category. Look at this answer. For your engulfing concern, this seems more like an objective. I believe minimizing the sum of the perimeter of the categories can give you what you want. You can count the perimeter by the number of times a variable x is touching a variable from a different category (so comparing $x_{ijk}$ with $x_{i+1 j k'}$ etc). Model might be huge, but it also ensures connectedness.

@sir.edward, thanks for clarification. Is there any preference to use the first 13 columns rather than the rest 27 columns? (e.g. there is a specific cost to use each of which?) Also, would $p_k$ be something like appropriate cost, or is it something like a capacity constraint (e.g. $p_1 = 50$ square, $p_2 = 70$ square, and so on)?

@A.Omidi no there is no preference to use the first 13, all of the space needs to be used ultimately. as shown in the objective function where I try to minimize the difference between $p_k$ and that sum divided by the total number of boxes, its the proportion of the boxes that need to be assigned to a specific category. This proportion is based on the popularity of different categories taking into account the density of the product. (this is internal stuff that's not relevant to the problem).

@J.Dionisio it seems like what I'm trying to do is borderline impossible (I'm still just a bachelor student), is there another way you would go about it? I have an area and 7 categories and need a certain area assigned to each category (with that being as close as possible to the $p_k$. I used boxes as I thought it would be easier but it can be looked at as just a regular area with no boundaries.

The "worker friendliness" criterion is a bit fuzzy. One possible approach is to bound the maximum $L_1$ distance between two boxes assigned to the same category. Another would be to bound the size of the smallest square containing all boxes in a given category. Either would promote compactness of each category region, with the danger that if the bound were set too tight it might make the model infeasible.
An alternative approach to consider would be to optimize compactness (minimize the maximum "size" of any category, where "size" uses one of the above criteria or perhaps some other) while bounding the maximum deviation of any category's box count from the target proportion $p_k.$

Try with below additional constraints
$(i*j)x_{i,j}^k \le z^k $
$p^k \le (i*j)x_{i,j}^k  \quad \forall (i,j) \ \ \forall k $
$z^k \le \max \{i *j \ \ \forall (ij) \}$
$\min \{i *j \ \ \forall (ij) \} \le p^k \quad \forall k$
Obj $\min \sum_k (z^k - p^k)$
